# How can I filter just one particular nick messages in weechat (IRC)

Tags: terminal, irc, weechat

Consider have a buffer/channel opened in your weechat. I want to temporarily see all the messages of one user/nick. Is this possible? This means only the filtered nick messages will be shown (just for a while).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use [`/filter`](https://weechat.org/files/doc/devel/weechat_user.en.html#command_weechat_filter):

```
/filter add <name> <buffer>[,<buffer>...] <tags> <regex>
```

You could use `<regex>` to match everything you don't like. However, maybe `!` works to negate tags, too. I'm not sure about that. You could try something like:

```
/filter add SHOWNICKNAMEONLY * !nick_NICKNAME *
```

The nick in this case would be `ǸICKNAME`. `nick_NICKNAME` is the tag which matches everything from `NICKNAME`. `!nick_NICKNAME` should match everything else.

Comment: Thanks, this works: `/filter add test * !nick_NICKNAME *` and I wanted to only show the messages of NICKNAME in all buffers. To restore original I either disable the whole filters or delete the test filter: `/filter del test`.